# How to add item to YML collection conditionally using Serverless framework?

Tags: yaml, serverless-framework, serverless

Given I have the following defined in a YML file for a resource:

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
  CallbackURLs:
    - "my-first-url"
```

How can I add a second item when only certain conditions are met? Unfortuantely it is not possible to simply set it to an empty string or null as it fails deployment validation. E.G something like:

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
  CallbackURLs:
    - "my-first-url"
    - myCondition ? "" : undefined // Omit item
```

Is this possible in any way at all? Happy to use Plugin solutions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CloudFormation condition like `Fn::If` to conditionally create stack resources. The [CloudFormation documentation about conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) has all the details but somehting like this should get you started:

```
resources:
  Conditions:
    my_condition: !Equals [value_1, value_2]
  Resources:
    MyUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
        CallbackURLs:
          - "my-first-url"
          - !If [my_condition, "...", !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

Replace the content of `my_condition` with your condition. It is referenced later in the `Fn::If` (the example uses the shorthand for `Fn::If`).

The `AWS::NoValue` is a pseudo parameter which can be used as a return value to remove the corresponding property. It *should* work here to remove the list item but I'm not sure about it, you'll need to test.